# Why happens to variable when cin breaks? C++

Tags: c++, cin

I have the following code snippet:

```
    int a = 1;
    double b = 3.14;
    string c = "hi";

    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
```

If I enter `apple 11 tammy`, why does it cout: `0 3.14 hi` instead of: `1 3.14 hi`?

Why does the value of `a` change when `cin` is broken?

Comment: So the "original value" is 3.14 and the "expectation" is 3.13 is the result? Or is this question now about a different value entirely? Being precise is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the value of `a` change when `cin` is broken?

This is the expected behavior of [std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) since C++11; If extraction fails the value will be set to `0`.

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and failbit flag is set.

Note that after `failbit` being set, the following input won't be performed; that means `b` and `c` will remain their original values.

BTW: Before C++11 the value will be left unmodified when extraction fails.

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

Answer (score 1):

Try stringstream instead. here is a link explaining the same issue in detail:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/